# libev: How to associate custom data with a watcher?

Tags: c, libev

I'm using libev for timers and io events in my Linux 'c' application, and I would like to associate custom data with events. In the libev docs, it alludes to [associating custom data](http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html#associating_custom_data_with_a_watcher) but gives no examples.

Could someone share how they did their associated custom data in their application?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just passing the watcher to the start function like so:

```
ev_io_init(&io_watcher);
ev_io_start(EV_A_ &io_watcher);
```

Make a struct with the watcher as the first member and pass that:

```
struct client {
    ev_io io;
    int socket;
};

// ... later ...

struct client *my_client = calloc(1, sizeof(struct client));
my_client->socket = socket;

ev_io_init(&(my_client->io), my_cb, socket, EV_READ);
ev_io_start(EV_A_ &(my_client->io));

// ... later ...

static void my_cb (struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w_, int revents) {
    struct client *w = (struct client *)w_;
    // ...
}
```

This is what the [documentation](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#ASSOCIATING_CUSTOM_DATA_WITH_A_WATCH) says to do, and what I use in my own projects.